# Solus distro is not booting anymore

Tags: linux, boot, journalctl, solus

Everything worked fine last time I used Solus, and now I cannot boot because of the error below.

Let's try to solve it without using a live USB.

[image]

[image]

```
**Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-partuuid/5ff8cfe6-53e1-43b1-9275-dc6f24ad812a**
```

Comment: What is your assessment of what is wrong? Can you try to type/include the relevant lines from journalctl as text in your question in code formatting? (datetime and hostname prefixes can be removed for improved reading).

Comment: @ProBackup the problem is that i cannot initialize the operative system, i  dont know how to copy the information of the photo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the man page, `fsck`'s error code 4 means **"Filesystem errors left uncorrected"**.

This is not good.  It means that the file system is corrupted beyond what is safe to automatically repair on boot, so manual intervention is required.

As the error message on your screen says, you need to manually run `fsck` to attempt to fix the errors.  You can probably do that from the initramfs root prompt (try `fsck /dev/sda6`).  If not, you'll need a rescue disk like [gparted](https://gparted.org/).  IMO, [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) also serves as a good rescue disk - it's got just about every file-system related utility you could possibly need.

Alternatively, since your Linux box is running `systemd`, you could interrupt the GRUB boot process and edit the linux kernel's command line  to make system perform a forced fsck:

- before `grub` times out and boots a kernel, press a key to cancel the timeout countdown.
- move the cursor as required to the entry you want to edit (probably the default menu entry).
- press `e` to enter `grub`'s editor.
- scroll through the editor and look for the line that starts with `linux` followed by a whole bunch of kernel options.
- add `fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=preen` to the end of that line.
- press F10 or Ctrl-X to accept the changes and boot that menu entry.

Note: these grub edits are **not** persistent across reboots.  They're temporary one-time changes for this boot session only.

Also note: it's possible that your filesystem is corrupted beyond repair.  `fsck` will do its best to get the fs back to a consistent state, but it's not magic: it can't repair or restore corrupted data.

Comment: Looks like fsck could be run from the emergency mode prompt, so it is not necessary to mess with GRUB.

Comment: @multithr3at3d - yes, that's why i mentioned the initrams root prompt first.

Comment: Isn't an initramfs shell different from the systemd rescue target terminology-wise? Just to clarify.

Comment: at the point that error will come up, it's still in an initramfs - the rootfs hasn't been mounted.  systemd doesn't replace initramfs, it uses it.

Comment: thank you guys very much! I will try and tell you as soon as I get home.

Comment: @cas I reinstalled the os... is there something I can do to prevent this kind of error?

Comment: fs corruption is not normal, so figuring out how to prevent it is difficult unless you can first find out what caused it.  possible causes include unclean reboot/shutdown while writing to the fs; failing disk; misuse (as root) of commands like `dd` that can write directly to the raw disk/partition.

Comment: I remember last time I boot I did it with sudo poweroff command... could it have made the error? Or it is the same as clicking the poweroff button?
How can I know I am having a clean shutdown? @cas

Comment: unlikely to be the cause - `poweroff` is safe to use unless you run it with the `-f` option to tell it not to call `shutdown`.   linux filesystems also tend to be very robust and even unclean shutdowns don't usually cause significant problems (i.e. beyond just lost the data in any file(s) that haven't been flushed to disk yet) unless you're very unlucky (e.g. power loss at precisely the wrong moment, such as while the system is updating important filesystem metadata) or there's some kind of hardware fault.   if it happens again, i'd suspect hardware problems.